Django urlpatterns including / at the back
I'm a student learning Django.
I have a question and I'd appreciate it if someone could help me.
When I navigate to 127.0.0.1:8000/feeds/1, it correctly displays the feed with ID 1.
However, I encounter an issue when I navigate to 127.0.0.1:8000/reviews/1, and I get the following error says page not found
This problem can be resolved by adding a slash in the reviews/urls.py path section like this: "int:review_id/".
My question is: why does the feeds URL work without the trailing slash in the urlpatterns, but for reviews I have to include the trailing slash to make it work?
here is the main urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("feeds/", include('feeds.urls')),
    path("users/", include('users.urls')),
    path("reviews/",include('reviews.urls'))
    # path("boards/", include('boards.urls'))
]

# feeds/urls.py

from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.Feeds.as_view()), 
    path("<int:feed_id>",views.FeedDetail.as_view()) 
]

# reviews/urls.py

from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.Reviews.as_view()),
    path("<int:review_id>/", views.ReviewDetail.as_view())
]



The answer is right in front of you. From your code:
path(
    "<int:feed_id>",    # <-- Notice no trailing '/'
    views.FeedDetail.as_view()) 

path(
    "<int:review_id>/", # <-- Notice trailing '/'
    views.ReviewDetail.as_view()) 

Or in other words, if you put '/' at the end of your path declaration, the '/' has to also be there when you enter your URL.

You did not include a trailing slash in:
path("<int:feed_id>",views.FeedDetail.as_view())

but you did in:
path("<int:review_id>/", views.ReviewDetail.as_view())

Background: When a user requests a page, Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first one that matches the requested URL, matching against path_info.
Once one of the URL patterns matches, Django imports and calls the given view, which is a Python function (or a class-based view). It is important to note that the URL requested by the user should match the URL set in the urlpatterns list (including the trailing slashes).
Also, I'll suggest you include a name parameter in your urlpatterns. The name parameter in URL patterns is used to provide a unique name to each URL. It allows you to refer to the URL by its name instead of hardcoding the URL in your code. This makes it easier to maintain and update URLs throughout your project. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls
